# If I use std::function to capture a lambda, should I worry about it being deallocated?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, lambda

Consider the following code,

```
std::function<void(void)> f = []() {};
std::function<void(void)>* fp = new std::function<void(void)>(f);
```

Whenever the program leaves the context of these lines (let's say they were called inside a function and the function returns) `f` and `fp`'s memory may be reclaimed at some point. Which is fine because I'm only interested in `fp` and I got a copy of it.

The point of this is having a function pointer (`fp`) that I can later invoke whenever I want. So, as long as I don't `delete fp`, the question is:

Will `f` ever be deallocated, rendering `fp` invalid?

Comment: It's the same situation as `int x = 1; int * xp = new int(x);`.

Comment: A different question is why you can't just store the function in a place where its lifetime overlaps with its use.

Comment: `std::function` is already a smart-pointer to a function object.

Comment: @Oliv it is no such thing. If anything, it holds the function object as a member.

Comment: @rubenvb You can hold a function object of arbitrary size in a `std::function`, so it can't (always) be a direct member. Remember that "smart-pointer" includes unique ownership

Comment: @rubenvb It is a smart pointer that owns a buffer for small object. This is equivalent to the short string optimization implemented by string. I prefered the term smart pointer over container because the right way to do is to make fb a unique_ptr to a std::function object. But this is just unusefull, std::function already implement safe owner-ship.

Comment: @Oliv Fair enough.

Comment: I'd call `std::function` a resource wrapper because the smart pointer analogy has some flaws. Nonetheless, it is similar enough to a smart pointer to make `std::unique_ptr<std::function<...>>` *usually* redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement:

```
std::function<void(void)>* fp = new std::function<void(void)>(f);
```

calls the copy constructor `function(std::function<void ()> const&)` and `f` is stored in the memory pointed to by `fp`.

So `fp` will not become invalid unless it is deleted.

As pointed out in the comments, it is the same as any other local variable which is used in the initialization of another variable whose memory is allocated using `new`. The life of the local variable does not affect the subsequent usage of the pointer variable unless the pointer itself is deleted.